# I have a problem with a personalized text

Tags: flutter, dart

THe principal problem is when i a put a text with textile with personalized font the heigh by default is 0.0, but when i try to change the height the space is infinite and the text dissapear.

```
Container(
                //height: 200,
                //width: 20,
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  "Parece que olvidaste tu\ncontraseña, ¿Qué deseas hacer?",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    //fontFamily: 'GothamBook',
                    height: 0.6,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                  ),
                ))
```

Comment: Can you put an image of the issue?

Comment: Please refine your question more, because I find it very hard to understand what is it that your trying to do here.